# Folder size range

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and I cannot work out how to satisfy the `-and` condition to search report on folders within a size range:

```
#Check if folder is over 950MB but less than 1GB
if ($subFolderItems.sum -gt 950000000 -and -lt 999999999)
{
$i.FullName + " Size Warning"
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost doing it right. You just need to add the variable for the second condition too:

```
if ($subFolderItems.sum -gt 950000000 -and $subFolderItems.sum -lt 999999999)
{
    $i.FullName + " Size Warning"
}
```

---

Also consider to divide your sum in `MB` and `GB` to improve the readability:

```
if (($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) -gt 950 -and ($subFolderItems.sum / 1GB) -lt 1)
{
    $i.FullName + " Size Warning"
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!