# Batch Script check folder Size with powershell command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am very new to batch scripting and there is one part that I miss on my script.

Basically I want to check if a specific folder(with sub-folders) is in between a specific size range. The normal size of the folder is around 200GB, so I read that you can not check the size in batch commands since cmd only works up to 2GB. So I would need to use a power-shell command in the batch script. 
So in the batch script I would check the folder size >190GB & <250GB with a power-shell command and the command would give back a return value if it is in the wanted range or not.

I found the following command:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -c "{0:N2} MB" -f ((Get-ChildItem C:\patch\to\file -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)
```

If you just type in the code in the Powershell you get a return value with the MB of the specific folder but I don't know how to go from there.

Comment: "cmd only works up to 2GB" - do you have any source for that? Sounds a bit strange in your context

Comment: @NicoHaase the `set /a` and `if` commands do only signed integer math with 32 bit accuracy.

Comment: Why not replacing the old and pretty much obsolete technology "batch" and do it with pure Powershell? It's more powerfull and sophisticated anyway.  ... and easier as well in my opinion. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf _"Pretty much obsolete technology.. "_ that is a very bold statement.

Comment: `powershell -c "'{0:#} MB' -f (((555,8888) | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / 1MB)"` shows how to [escape `cmd` poisonous characters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) like `|`, `&` etc. in command passed to `powershell`.  BTW, it's pretty unclear how do you want to treat a value  returned…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Folder size range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830477/folder-size-range)

Answer (score 3):

In general I agree that PowerShell is the more modern and feature rich shell but if that is not feasible:

- In your PowerShell command you need to escape the double quotes with a backslash and the pipe with a caret to keep those from being interpreted by cmd.exe
- batch needs a pure integer number, so change the format specifier `\"{0:N2} MB\"` to `\"{0:N0}\"`
- to process the output of another command in batch parse it with a `for /f`

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\09\SO_50247759.cmd
@Echo off
Set "Folder=C:\Test"
:: TargetSize in  GB * 1024 = MB
:: _PlusMinus as percent
:: _UpperB, _LowerB  are the calculated bounds
:: you may set bounds to fixed values
Set /A _TargetSize=200*1024, _PlusMinus=5, _Upperb=_TargetSize+_TargetSize*_PlusMinus/100, _LowerB=_TargetSize-_TargetSize*_PlusMinus/100
For /f "delims=" %%S in ('
powershell -Exec Unrestricted -c \"{0:N0}\" -f ((GCI \"%Folder%\" -R^^^|Measure Length -Sum -EA 1^).Sum/1MB^)
') Do Set "FolderSize=%%S"

If %FolderSize% gtr %_UpperB% (
  Echo Size %FolderSize% of %Folder% is greater than upper bound %_UpperB%
  Exit /B 2
) else ( 
  If %FolderSize% lss %_LowerB% (
    Echo Size %FolderSize% of %Folder% is less than lower bound %_LowerB%
    Exit /b 1
  ) 
)
Echo Size %FolderSize% of %Folder% is within lower bound %_LowerB% and upper bound %_UpperB%
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_50247759.cmd
Size 173 of C:\Test is less than lower bound 194560
```